# How to create and populate a label on TradingView using Pine Editor?

Tags: finance, pine-script

When trading I try to calculate the size of my initial position based on the initial capital I am willing to use and the value of the stock.

Now I want to create a script in the Pine Editor that takes the price of the stock and takes into account the amount of capital available. It should then tell me how big the position should be. And what the quarters and thirds are so that I can scale out of positions.

It would be nice if this could be shown as a label, as shown on the image.

[image: Example image]

Anyone can help me please? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, unfortunatelly, there's no way to print out any calculated value yet.